# Extend Arrows Missing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I upgraded my Visual Studio to the latest version 15.3.1 yesterday. Since then, I noticed that the little arrows that help you extend an element are missing -- see below:

[image]

Prior to my update, I was using Visual Studio 2017 15.3 and the arrows were there. Even though the arrows are missing, I'm able to extend items. It's just a nuisance really.

Anyone else is having this issue? Any known fixes?

Comment: This was mentioned/noted in SO C# chat yesterday but I have no further information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same happened to me after the upgrade. I solved this by replacing the file `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_{id}\ImageLibrary\ImageLibrary.cache` with a copy from a working setup.

Credit goes to: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/95295/view.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm following this issue on developer community too. Thanks again!